# 1 large SQL Query executes multiple single queries for each row in Zend

Tags: sql, postgresql, zend-framework

Title may be little unclear but I will explain:

The following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.something FROM table1 as m  LEFT JOIN table2 as t ON
t.id = m.id  LEFT JOIN table3 as c ON t.id = c.id  WHERE ... LIMIT
1000;
```

has a limit of 1000. Now that's the only query executed in The specific action, now Zend debug tool is installed and when I look at the sql queries which are executed on that page, I see that this query is executed together with the following one a 1000 times (for every row in result 1 time with id of each row:

```
SELECT "table1".* FROM table1 WHERE ((("table1"."id" = *id*)))
```

This makes the performance of the page really slow, and I don't think all these queries are necessary so I'm looking for a solution so all these queries aren't executed anymore and the performance will be better.

Anyone who recognizes this situation?

PS: maybe good to know is that i use Postgresql together with Zend framework

Comment: You need to provide your full query. The `WHERE` clause matters. And the version numbers of your software - as always. And are you sure you want **`t`** `.something`, even though you only `LEFT JOIN t`?

Answer (score 1):

This is more like an ancient riddle where one has to *guess* his way through than a programmer's question.

You seem to need more than `something` on your page, yet your query only retrieves `something`. Then your underwhelmingly smart app fetches every single row separately - a performance disaster.

I also *guess*, that the query you provide in the question is *wrong* (besides being inefficient) and should read:

```
SELECT DISTINCT m.something
FROM   table1 as m
LEFT   JOIN table2 as t ON t.id = m.id
LEFT   JOIN table3 as c ON t.id = c.id
WHERE  ...
LIMIT  1000;
```

.. which is probably still nonsense, depending on your actual `WHERE` clause, that you kept from us.

To retrieve the whole row (or just the columns you need) with table aliases that make sense:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.*
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.id = t1.id
LEFT JOIN table3 t3 ON t3.id = t2.id
WHERE ...
LIMIT 1000;
```

To do the same more efficiently (provided there are no dupes in `table1` to begin with):

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM   table1 t1
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM   table2      t2
    LEFT   JOIN table3 t3 USING (id)
    WHERE  ON t2.id = t1.id
    )
AND ...
LIMIT 1000;
```

Comment: first of all, thank you for your answer and feedback on my query to make it more efficient. I've changed the query in my code but my problem still remains. He keeps executing a single query for every row in the resultset.